# C# Console Application to Respond to HTTP POST requests

Tags: c#, .net, http, sockets, post

Is it possible to respond to HTTP POST requests in a C# console application?  If so, how?  I'm thinking it may involve the use of sockets (which I know very little about).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: well, what are you using? asp.net? asp.net mvc? maybe this can help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx

Comment: @AndreiNeagu Unfortunately, it's not a web app, just a standard C# console application.  Thanks for the assist though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use sockets - .NET has had an HTTP/1.1 server since v2.0.

See: [MSDN: HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034721/handling-multiple-requests-with-c-sharp-httplistener

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ASP.Net Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) which has been developed for this exact purpose.

> ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers and mobile devices.

Comment: I assumed he didn't mean a web app :)

Comment: @NicholasButler You're right, it's not a web app; it's a standard C# console application.  I probably should've provided more detail in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on you`r question is yes, but only if you create some kind of HTTP server that would listen to HTTP requests or using open source server like:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25050/Embedded-NET-HTTP-Server
http://webserver.codeplex.com/