# Asynchronous await Task.Delay significantly reduces bandwidth of HttpListener based server

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I use standard **HttpListener** from **System.Net** namespace. When I use **Task.Delay** to simulate some work on server side (without await) and test server with Apache benchmark it gives good results (2000 rps). But when I'm "awaiting" bandwith is about 9 rps (according to Apache Benchmark). Why is it behave like this? Appreciate for answers.

```
private async Task Listen()
{
    while (listener.IsListening)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = await listener.GetContextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            // good without await
            await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);

            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream))
            {
                await sw.WriteAsync("<html><body>Hello</body></html>");
                await sw.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}

public async Task Run()
{
    listener.Start();
    Task.Run(() => Listen());
}
```

Comment: How actually are you doing it without `await`?

Comment: `Task.Delay()` is non-blocking. It creates a `Task` which will complete after the specified delay. If you aren't awaiting it, what are you doing?

Comment: "blocking Task.Delay"? What is that?

Comment: You put a 100ms delay in the loop which means only 10 iterations can complete in a second. `Task.Delay()` doesn't affect the bandwidth. The code throttled the listener to only 1 request per 100ms

Comment: I don't know where did you get that sample, but you should have used one from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034721/handling-multiple-requests-with-c-sharp-httplistener if you are building server that handles multiple requests in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the pause you've inserted delays the loop.

You only accept requests on the line:

```
await listener.GetContextAsync()
```

***which is in this same loop.***

This means that you have to wait for the previous request to complete before you accept a new context.

Most likely, you want to handle the accepted contexts concurrently. To achieve this, you should accept contexts in a tight loop, then spin off the handling of the request to a different place which doesn't "hang" the accept loop.

At it's simplest, you could "fire and forget"...

```
while (listener.IsListening)
{
    var context = await listener.GetContextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    HandleContextAsync(context); //note: not awaited
}
```

...in reality, you'll need to think a bit harder about how to track exceptions in the `HandleContextAsync` method.

Comment: Sorry for additional answer, I moved context handling to another place and now it's good, but now I have another problem (ironically, this is my initial problem). When I test server with  5000 concurrent requets (-c in Apache Benchmar) it throws **System.Net.HttpListenerException: "An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection"**. Without await Task.Delay that not happens. https://pastebin.com/z2Q441zz

Comment: @enceladus this is a completely different question, so just create another one for that.

Answer (score 1):

The `Delay()` Task is created and allowed to run in its own time, without influencing the creating method any further. If you neither `await` (asynchronous) or `Wait()` (synchronous) on that Task, then the creating method carries on immediately, making it appear 'fast'. `await` *actually waits* for the delay Task to complete, but does it in a way that means the thread does not block and can execute other work concurrently. Your other version doesn't wait *at all*, synchronously or otherwise. The delay Task is created and runs, but since nothing else cares when it finishes, it just gets executed and garbage-collected playing no further part in the method.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you wait 100 ms before processing a next request, so you can process maximum 10 requests per second. Task.Delay without await doesn't affect your application at all, you can remove this line and as a result still will be handle 2000 request per second.